# Sign-in with Apple from device using NextAuth.js

Tags: next-auth, sign-in-with-apple

When using the [Apple provider](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/apple) with NextAuth.js on the web server and signing in on a native device app (written in Swift using [ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidbutton) and [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidprovider)) using Sign In With Apple, how do you add a new user and account to the NextAuth.js [database tables](https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/models)?

Besides signing into the iOS app, the user also needs to be able to sign into a website with Sign In With Apple and link his user account to other OAuth providers like Google (e.g. if signing in on Android). This question focuses on just Sign In With Apple on an iOS device and how to record that account info so that it plays nicely with sign-ins on other platforms.

Does NextAuth.js have a REST API that the iOS device can call to do this? Otherwise, if custom code on the Next.js server is needed to add the rows manually, is there documentation on what goes into each of the columns in NextAuth.js user and account tables?

Answer (score 0):

if you just setup the `AppleProvider`, NextAuth.js won't keep a database of your users.

It lets Apple handle that and then just gets a signed message back saying, im paraphrasing, "Yup, thats Edward, and here are some more details about him.." and includes some basic info like your email address, profile picture URL, etc.

This is the basics of their OAuth-only strategy.

If you'd like to persist user data yourself and maybe add additional fields to the ones Apple returns to you, you'll have to setup an adapter. An adapter in NextAuth.js world is just a database where it will automatically save any new users and check against for existing users.

You can see the details of the various available adapters, including the default model/schema here: https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/models

Comment: I'm using a database because the user needs to be able to also sign in on a website and optionally link his account to other OAuth providers. I added a second paragraph to my question to clarify. I added an adapter and am using the models per your link. However, I haven't found documentation for the fields in the `Account` table in the model or the mapping from Apple's fields.

Comment: No so theres nothing special you need to do here for iOS or anything. Just follow the normal instructions for setting up NextAuth.js with the database adapter of your choice, and setup the Apple OAuth provider.

This will enable the "Sign in with Apple" button on your app which will allow them to signin with their iCloud accounts.

Comment: The mobile app is a native iOS app written in Swift and using [ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidbutton) and [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidprovider). (I clarified the question to mention that.) The iOS app sends the Auth results to web server, which then needs to provide them to NextAuth.js. It's not clear how to do that.

Comment: Yeah this might not be the right library for you in this case. This is designed for web application written in javascript / Next.js.

I'm sure theres more appropriate OAuth libraries for iOS / Swift. 

What makes you want to use NextAuth.js here?

Comment: There is a Next.js website that serves as a companion to iOS and Android apps. The user will be able to sign into either app or the website using Apple, Google, or Facebook. NextAuth.js seems like a good way to handle auth on the website - if I can integrate authentication from the app. Or if you have a suggestion for a more appropriate library, please let me know.

Comment: Yeah so if you just want to do "Sign in with Google" or "Signin with Apple" OAuth sign-in in the webapp, then NextAuth.js is appropriate. Its just not the right app for the iOS app version.

Comment: Makes sense. Which leads me to my original "Otherwise" question, which is essentially: In the case of using NextAuth to handle the web-based auth and using custom code to handle app-based auth, where can I look to see how the custom code should write to NextAuth's database tables in a way that plays nicely with it? For example, it isn't clear what if anything goes in the `accounts` table in `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`.

Comment: Yes, good catch! Those two values are kept only for backward compatibility for OAuth v1.0 (which was still used by Twitter at the time of publishing the latest major version). Twitter recently announced OAuth 2.0 (+ OIDC) support recently, however.  (See: https://next-auth.js.org/adapters/models#account)

Anyway, NextAuth.js takes care of writing users to the database for you if you follow the example app (https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/tree/main/apps/example-nextjs) and add the database part. Check the "custom schema" section in the docs if you need additional fields.